# Validate model regular expression in controller in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.Net MVC 4 and created model and validation like this

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
[StringLength(50)]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9 -']+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
public String FullName { get; set; }
```

It is validating properly on clint side.

I am already checking

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    return View(Model);
```

But when validating with IBM AppScan, it posts data directly like `John' or 1 = 1 --` and shows issue of Blind Sql Injection.

Debug the code and try to change the full name value to `John' or 1 = 1 --` and ModelState is still showing valid.

I want to validate the model RegEx in controller, is there any way to validate it in controller?

Answer (score 0):

Blind SQLi testing is often a hit & miss in terms of automated application security test tools.  Try to do a retest in appscan using a single thread on the Blind SQLi issue and see if it'd just simply be removed as false positive.